# why different output of ' grep "*.h" ' and ' grep -E "*.h" ' on the same file

Tags: regex, linux, grep, gnu

Suppose the file content is as below:

> ```
> abc.h  
> hello world
> ```

the output of `grep "*.h" file` and `grep -E "*.h" file` are different. From my understanding, they should be the same. `*` is a regular expression meta-character. The output should both be `abc.h`.

**Output with**

```
grep "*.h" file     # ==> No output
grep -E "*.h" file  # ==> abc.h
```

Please help clarifying this issue!

Comment: So ... what IS the output?

Comment: Regular expressions work differently than wildcard patterns.

Comment: I think that (strangely) the ERE seems to allow a kind of orphan quantifier (a quantifier for an empty token) when BRE doesn't allow that. Whatever the explanation, the dot must be escaped to figure a literal dot.

Comment: What do you expect `*.h` to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX defines the behaviour of (POSIX) [regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) and defines Basic Regular Expressions (BREs) and Extended Regular Expressions (EREs).  Using `grep -E` requires EREs; without the `-E`, you get BREs (with `-F` you get no regular expressions).

The POSIX definition of `*` in a BRE says:

> `*`
>       The `<asterisk>` shall be special except when used:
>
> - In a bracket expression
> - As the first character of an entire BRE (after an initial '^', if any)

The POSIX definition of `*` in an ERE says:

> `*+?{`
>       The `<asterisk>`, `<plus-sign>`, `<question-mark>`, and `<left-brace>` shall be special except when used in a bracket expression (see RE Bracket Expression). Any of the following uses produce undefined results:
>
> - If these characters appear first in an ERE, or immediately following a `<vertical-line>`, `<circumflex>`, or `<left-parenthesis>`

In the question:

- Using `grep '*.h'` is using a BRE and the `*` appears first so it is not a special character; it matches a `*` followed by any character followed by `h`.

  ```
  This would be matched *Zh because the * and the h are separated by one character
  This would not be matched because the * and the h are not separated by one character
  ```
- Using `grep -E '*.h'` invokes undefined behaviour.  Any result is valid.

To reliably match `abc.h` and other alphanumeric file names ending with `.h`, you'd use something like:

```
grep '[[:alnum:]]\.h'
```

There's no particular need to use the `*` in this context; if you did, you might write one of these:

```
grep '^[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*\.h$'
grep '^[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\.h$'
```

These look for lines that consist of one or more alphanumerics, followed by `.` and `h` and end-of-line.  If you don't like the character class expression notation (the `[:alnum:]` part), you can write this instead:

```
grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\.h$'
grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,\}\.h$'
```

You can add underscores if you like:

```
grep '^[[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\.h$'
grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.h$'
```

And you can use extended regular expressions like:

```
grep '^[[:alnum:]_]+\.h$'
grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.h$'
```

Etcetera.  The options are legion!

Answer (score 3):

`*.h` shouldn't match either line. If it does, it's because your particular grep's extended regular expression engine handles boundaries or quantifiers differently. You may see this odd behavior with GNU grep, but BSD grep correctly reports `grep: repetition-operator operand invalid` instead.

You probably meant `.*h`, which will match both lines whether you use the BRE or ERE engine. If you only want to match `abc.h` from the provided corpus, then you need:

```
grep '\.h' /tmp/foo
```

This will match any line with a literal period followed by the letter `h`. You might even want to anchor it at the end of the line to be sure you don't capture text like `foo abc.h bar` by mistake. For example:

```
grep '\.h$' /tmp/foo
```

Comment: I think the output is different with ERE,  outputs abc.h

Comment: @Tejendra Only with GNU grep, and that's *probably* because its ERE interprets boundaries differently. You'd have to look at the source to be sure. BSD sed will correctly report `grep: repetition-operator operand invalid` instead.

Comment: @CodeGnome...I was trying on Debian Jessie

Comment: Why do you mention `sed`?

Answer (score 0):

`-E` - extended regular expression, where `*` means *The preceding item will be matched zero or more times*

`-G` (default) - basic regular expression, where `*` means just the `*` character

`-P` - Perl regular expression, where `*` means the same as in `-E`, but `*.h` fails to compile because there is nothing to repeat(no characters before `*`). Uses `libpcre`:

```
ldd /bin/grep 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffefddd4000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x0000003bd8a00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003bd6a00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003bd7200000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003bd6600000)
```

So `grep -E "*.h"` will match any string having `.h` sequence;
`grep -G "*.h"` will match any string having `*.h` sequence; `grep -P "*.h"` will fail to compile.

Comment: `*` generally means the same thing in basic and extended regular expressions. Any difference, as we're seeing here, applies only when the `*` isn't preceded by anything.

Comment: In BRE, `*` means 'the preceding item will be matched zero or more times' when there is a preceding item.